# How do I append a new line to a bash file using Laravel's file append method?

Tags: php, laravel, bash, append, ssh2

I am attempting to insert a new line so the dynamic callback can be added however I'm not having much success; the curl isn't on a brand new line which breaks the script. It is instead on the last line alongside a mkdir.

```
File::put(storage_path('app/scripts/'.$rand.'.script'), $this->deployment->script);

File::append(storage_path('app/scripts/'.$rand.'.script'), '  \n');
// Doesn't break onto a new line. 

File::append(storage_path('app/scripts/'.$rand.'.script'), $callbackURL);

$sendFile = ssh2_scp_send($connection, storage_path('app/scripts/'.$rand.'.script'), 'deploy.sh');
ssh2_exec($connection, 'sh deploy.sh');
```

Any assistance would be appreciated! Thank you so much.

Comment: New line characters should be in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: just replace `, '  \n');` with `, "\n");` double quotes interprit what's in the string while single quote does not.